# Can we compare coefficients from log-log and log-linear regression?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, interpretation, linear, logarithm

We have two regressions
$$ 
ln(Y) = \alpha_1 + \beta_1 ln(X) + \epsilon \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
and
$$ 
ln(Y) = \alpha_2 + \beta_2 X + \epsilon \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
In the first case, a 1% increase in $X$ increases $Y$ by $e^{\beta_1*log(1.01)}$, which is approximately $\beta_1$%.

In the second case, a one unit increase in $X$ increases $Y$ by $e^{\beta_2}$, or approximately $100 \times \beta_2$ percentage points.

Say we know that $\hat{\beta_1}=0.05$ and $\hat{\beta_2} = 0.10$ estimated in different samples, but also using the different specifications. Can we say something about which coefficient is larger without further information  on $X$?

Comment: The coefficients aren't even in the same units of measurement!  You aren't comparing apples to oranges: you're comparing apples to real estate.

Comment: Thank you. But with information on X we can transform the coefficients using the mean in X and applying d ln(x) = d x / x?

Comment: Exactly what "information on $X$" do you mean? Regardless, the two models differ: in the first one, a unit change in $X$ is associated with *different* changes in $\log(Y)$ depending on the value of $X,$ while in the second one all those associated changes in $\log(Y)$ are constant.  Thus, you are trying to compare a *variable* slope to a *constant* one.

Comment: I've seen it being done in meta-studies that multiply the semi-elasticity from equation (2) with 1/mean(X) and arguing that the semi-elasticity at the mean of X is equal to the elasticity from equation (1)